# Is it possible for Azure Kinect Body Tracking to accept depth data from a different depth camera?

Tags: kinect-v2, azurekinect

This is being done in a Unity project.

I'm currently experimenting with creating a new Azure Kinect Capture object and filling it with data from the color, depth, and IR frames being created by the K2. Since an Azure Kinect camera isn't supposed to be in use at the time, I create a fake Azure Kinect Calibration to be used in the creation of an Azure Kinect Bodytracking Tracker.

I'm running into a problem where if the data pulled from the Kinect v2 is successfully enqueued, the project hangs, and if a call is made to pop the enqueued data, the project hangs as soon as its run. I've added timeouts to the enqueue and pop, which fixed the freezing, however the popped BodyTracking Frame object never contains a body. I've set up a scene where the depth data is visualized to make sure its not being distorted or obscured and it looks fine.

Before I continue trying to make this work, I wanted to see if I was missing something here or if what I'm doing is even possible.

The fake calibration:

```
Calibration cal = new Calibration {
                DepthCameraCalibration = new CameraCalibration {
                    Extrinsics = new Extrinsics {
                        Rotation = new float[] { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
                        Translation = new float[] { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }
                    },
                    Intrinsics = new Intrinsics {
                        Type = CalibrationModelType.BrownConrady,
                        ParameterCount = 14,
                        Parameters = new float[] { 264.902374f, 261.016541f, 251.993011f, 252.0128f, 0.5496079f, -0.0305904336f, -0.00340628251f, 0.893285751f, 0.07668319f, -0.01748066f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }
                    },
                    ResolutionWidth = 512,
                    ResolutionHeight = 512,
                    MetricRadius = 1.73999977f
                },
                ColorCameraCalibration = new CameraCalibration {
                    Extrinsics = new Extrinsics {
                        Rotation = new float[] { 0.9999973f, 0.00189682352f, -0.00130836014f, -0.00179401657f, 0.997216046f, 0.07454452f, 0.00144611555f, -0.07454198f, 0.9972168f },
                        Translation = new float[] { -32.1138039f, -2.46932817f, 3.97587371f }
                    },
                    Intrinsics = new Intrinsics {
                        Type = CalibrationModelType.BrownConrady,
                        ParameterCount = 14,
                        Parameters = new float[] { 957.2569f, 551.9336f, 913.142334f, 913.1438f, 0.4421505f, -2.83680415f, 1.73018765f, 0.32017225f, -2.644007f, 1.643955f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -0.000281378743f, 0.000288581447f, 0.0f }
                    },
                    ResolutionWidth = 1920,
                    ResolutionHeight = 1080,
                    MetricRadius = 1.7f
                },
                DeviceExtrinsics = new Extrinsics[] { //Device Extrinsics calibration chunk
                    new Extrinsics(){ Rotation = new float[] { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },                                                                                   Translation = new float[] { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f } },
                    new Extrinsics(){ Rotation = new float[] { 0.9999973f, 0.00189682352f, -0.00130836014f, -0.00179401657f, 0.997216046f, 0.07454452f, 0.00144611555f, -0.07454198f, 0.9972168f },      Translation = new float[] { -32.1138039f, -2.46932817f, 3.97587371f } },
                    new Extrinsics(){ Rotation = new float[] { -0.000347044057f, 0.110655256f, -0.9938588f, -0.999971569f, -0.007524097f, -0.000488546968f, -0.00753195f, 0.9938304f, 0.110654727f },    Translation = new float[] { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f } },
                    new Extrinsics(){ Rotation = new float[] { 0.00211483915f, 0.106267117f, -0.994335353f, -0.999981642f, -0.005419674f, -0.00270606228f, -0.00567653868f, 0.994322836f, 0.1062537f },  Translation = new float[] { -51.137455f, 3.33257771f, 0.7745425f } },
                    new Extrinsics(){ Rotation = new float[] { 0.9999973f, -0.00179401657f, 0.00144611555f, 0.00189682352f, 0.997216046f, -0.07454198f, -0.00130836014f, 0.07454452f, 0.9972168f },      Translation = new float[] { 32.10354f, 2.81973743f, -3.82274985f } },
                    new Extrinsics(){ Rotation = new float[] { 0.99999994f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.99999994f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },                                                                     Translation = new float[] { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f } },
                    new Extrinsics(){ Rotation = new float[] { 0.00116317568f, 0.0362610966f, -0.9993417f, -0.9999825f, -0.005745603f, -0.00137240067f, -0.00579158543f, 0.9993258f, 0.03625378f },      Translation = new float[] { 4.100151f, -32.1219749f, 2.13753319f } },
                    new Extrinsics(){ Rotation = new float[] { 0.00361735234f, 0.0318452343f, -0.999486268f, -0.9999857f, -0.00381232449f, -0.00374062685f, -0.0039294865f, 0.9994855f, 0.0318309739f }, Translation = new float[] { -46.96882f, -28.77531f, 2.98985362f } },
                    new Extrinsics(){ Rotation = new float[] { -0.000347044057f, -0.999971569f, -0.00753195f, 0.110655256f, -0.007524097f, 0.9938304f, -0.9938588f, -0.000488546968f, 0.110654727f },    Translation = new float[] { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f } },
                    new Extrinsics(){ Rotation = new float[] { 0.00116317568f, -0.9999825f, -0.00579158543f, 0.0362610966f, -0.005745603f, 0.9993258f, -0.9993417f, -0.00137240067f, 0.03625378f },      Translation = new float[] { -32.1138039f, -2.46932817f, 3.97587371f } },
                    new Extrinsics(){ Rotation = new float[] { 1.00000012f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.00000012f },                                                                     Translation = new float[] { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f } },
                    new Extrinsics(){ Rotation = new float[] { 0.999987245f, -0.00242856354f, -0.0044323504f, 0.002436766f, 0.9999953f, 0.00184613629f, 0.00442783535f, -0.00185691414f, 0.9999885f },   Translation = new float[] { -51.137455f, 3.33257771f, 0.7745425f } },
                    new Extrinsics(){ Rotation = new float[] { 0.00211483915f, -0.999981642f, -0.00567653868f, 0.106267117f, -0.005419674f, 0.994322836f, -0.994335353f, -0.00270606228f, 0.1062537f },  Translation = new float[] { 3.44506049f, 4.682146f, -50.92106f } },
                    new Extrinsics(){ Rotation = new float[] { 0.00361735234f, -0.9999857f, -0.0039294865f, 0.0318452343f, -0.00381232449f, 0.9994855f, -0.999486268f, -0.00374062685f, 0.0318309739f }, Translation = new float[] { -28.5932484f, -1.602283f, -47.1475f } },
                    new Extrinsics(){ Rotation = new float[] { 0.999987245f, 0.002436766f, 0.00442783535f, -0.00242856354f, 0.9999953f, -0.00185691414f, -0.0044323504f, 0.00184613629f, 0.9999885f },   Translation = new float[] { 51.125248f, -3.45531416f, -1.0073452f } },
                    new Extrinsics(){ Rotation = new float[] { 0.99999994f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },                                                                            Translation = new float[] { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f } }
                },
                DepthMode = DepthMode.WFOV_2x2Binned,
                ColorResolution = ColorResolution.R1080p
            };
            #endregion

            tracker = Tracker.Create(cal, new TrackerConfiguration() {
                SensorOrientation = SensorOrientation.Default,
                ProcessingMode = TrackerProcessingMode.Gpu,
                GpuDeviceId = 0
            });
```

The depth into bodytracking process:

```
timeSinceStart = DateTime.Now.Subtract(timeOfStart);


            colorFrame = colorFrameReader.AcquireLatestFrame();
            depthFrame = depthFrameReader.AcquireLatestFrame();
            irFrame = infraredFrameReader.AcquireLatestFrame();

            KinectCapture capture = new KinectCapture();

            if (colorFrame != null) {

                Image colorImage = new Image(ImageFormat.ColorBGRA32, colorFrame.FrameDescription.Width, colorFrame.FrameDescription.Height) {
                    DeviceTimestamp = timeSinceStart
                };
                colorImage.SystemTimestampNsec = timeSinceStart.Milliseconds * 1000000;

                if (colorBuffer == null) {
                    FrameDescription description = colorFrame.ColorFrameSource.FrameDescription;
                    colorBuffer = new byte[description.BytesPerPixel * description.Width * description.Height];
                }

                colorFrame.CopyRawFrameDataToArray(colorBuffer);

                for (int i = 0; i < 2073600; i++) {
                    ushort uShort = BitConverter.ToUInt16(colorBuffer, i * 2);
                    colorImage.SetPixel<ushort>(i % 1080, i / 1080, uShort);
                }

                capture.Color = colorImage;
                colorFrame.Dispose();
            }

            if (depthFrame != null) {

                Image depthImage = new Image(ImageFormat.Depth16, 512, 512);
                depthImage.DeviceTimestamp = timeSinceStart;
                depthImage.SystemTimestampNsec = timeSinceStart.Milliseconds * 1000000;



                if (depthBuffer == null) {
                    var description = depthFrame.DepthFrameSource.FrameDescription;
                    depthBuffer = new ushort[description.Width * description.Height];
                }

                depthFrame.CopyFrameDataToArray(depthBuffer);

                for (int i = 0; i < 262144; i++) {
                    if(i < depthBuffer.Length)
                    {
                        depthImage.SetPixel<ushort>(i % 512, i / 512, depthBuffer[i]);

                    } else
                    {
                        depthImage.SetPixel<ushort>(i % 512, i / 512, 0);
                    }

                }

                capture.Depth = depthImage;
                depthFrame.Dispose();
            }

            if (irFrame != null) {

                Image irImage = new Image(ImageFormat.IR16, 512, 512);
                irImage.DeviceTimestamp = timeSinceStart;
                irImage.SystemTimestampNsec = timeSinceStart.Milliseconds * 1000000;

                if (irBuffer == null) {
                    var description = irFrame.InfraredFrameSource.FrameDescription;
                    irBuffer = new ushort[description.Width * description.Height];
                }

                irFrame.CopyFrameDataToArray(depthBuffer);

                for (int i = 0; i < 262144; i++) {
                    if (i < irBuffer.Length)
                    {
                        irImage.SetPixel<ushort>(i % 512, i / 512, irBuffer[i]);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        irImage.SetPixel<ushort>(i % 512, i / 512, 0);
                    }
                }

                capture.IR = irImage;
                irFrame.Dispose();
            }

            capture.Temperature = 30.0f;

            try {
                if(capture.Color != null && capture.Depth != null && capture.IR != null)
                {
                    tracker.EnqueueCapture(capture, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 50));
                    Debug.Log("Successful Enqueue");
                }
                
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Debug.Log($"Failed to enqeue\n{ex.Message}");
            }

            try {
                kFrame = tracker.PopResult(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 15));
                
                Debug.Log("Bodies in frame: " + kFrame.NumberOfBodies);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Debug.Log($"Failed to pop from queue\n{ex.Message}");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Body Tracking SDK is designed to work with Azure Kinect devices.